# Converting from csv to json by using map for more than 1 depth level

Tags: java, json, csv, hashmap, typeconverter

I have a csv file which has contents like :

```
Fruit, Mango
Fruit, Apple
Car, Audi
Apple, Red
Color, Brown
```

I want to eventually convert it in a format like this :

```
"hierarchy" : [{
   "label": "Fruit",
   "children" : [ {label: "Mango"}, {label: "Apple", "children": [ {label:"Red"}]}
   ]
},
{
   "label" : "Car",
   "children" : [ {label: "Audi"}
   ]
},
{
   "label" : "Color",
   "children" : [ {label: "Brown"}
   ]
}]
```

To do this, I have inserted the values in the map :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();
 while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

String[] contents=(sb.toString().split("\n"));
String[] newContents;

 Map<String, List<String>> myMaps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();


for(String s : contents)
{
  newContents= s.split(",");
    if (!myMaps.containsKey(newContents[0])) {
            myMaps.put(newContents[0], new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        myMaps.get(newContents[0]).add(newContents[1]);
}
```

This will basically convert the file to a map in the form of parent (key) and child (values). I was however wondering how to deal with the case when there is more than 1 level of depth - For example in my given csv? Will a map work in this case or is there a better approach?

Comment: To map key-value pairs there is only `java.util.Map` interface. Or you can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library

Comment: How will it map for multiple depth levels?

Comment: You can use `java.util.Map` as value of outer `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON structure looks more like a tree, that can be desined as a class:

```
public class Node {
    private String label;
    private List<Node> children; // can also be of type Node[]

    // getters, setters
}
```

then hierarchy is an array or List of nodes

List is preferred over array, because it is easier to use during population of children

UPDATE:
The full example on how to populate the Tree using `Node` class:

```
public class Node {
    private String label;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>(); // to avoid checks for null

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}

class Converter {
    public List<Node> fromCsvFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        Node root = new Node();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String[] entry;

        String line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            entry = line.split(",");

            // find or create
            Node node = findByLabel(root, entry[0]);
            if (node == null) {
                // top level
                node = new Node();
                node.setLabel(entry[0]);
                root.getChildren().add(node);
            }

            // add child
            Node child = new Node();
            child.setLabel(entry[1]);
            node.getChildren().add(child);

            // next line
            line = input.readLine();
        }

        return root.getChildren();
    }

    public Node findByLabel(Node node, String label) {
        if (label.equals(node.getLabel())) {
            return node;
        }

        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            // recursion
            Node found = findByLabel(child, label);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: You do not need explicit `Node`, and you can use `Map<String, Object>` where a value can contain nested maps, or List of children, or String value for label. But using an explicit class is cleaner.

Alternative to recursive lookup for an existing node in the tree, an independent flat collection (Map) can be created to speed up lookups:

```
class Converter {
    public List<Node> fromCsvFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        Node root = new Node();
        Map<String, Node> existingNodes = new HashMap<>();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String[] entry;

        String line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            entry = line.split(",");

            // find or create
            Node node = existingNodes.get(entry[0]);
            if (node == null) {
                // new top level node
                node = new Node();
                node.setLabel(entry[0]);
                root.getChildren().add(node);
                existingNodes.put(entry[0], node);
            }

            // add child
            Node child = new Node();
            child.setLabel(entry[1]);
            node.getChildren().add(child);
            existingNodes.put(entry[1], child);

            // next line
            line = input.readLine();
        }

        return root.getChildren();
    }
}
```

Just for reference: [Full example](https://pastebin.com/3afNGSCa)

Comment: How will my map work to generate a JSON of this format? (It could work for depth of 1, but how do I create a map where the level can be more than 2?).

Comment: @TeeJay something like that

Comment: @TeeJay there is still a challenge to reorganize a tree if a top level node suddenly is mentioned as a child of another node in the lower record of CSV file, at that moment the node should be moved from `root` children to the new node children, this should be done prior "add child" logic

Comment: This can be avoided if there is a constraint on the CSV like have the children mentioned in order, right? (Instead of somewhere else in the lower record?) For example : A,B /n A,C /n B,D /n C,E /n F,G. After the map is created, would calling a JSON serializer convert it to the specified json format?

Comment: @TeeJay yes, if you have ordered data (root nodes are always mentioned before their children) you do not need any additional logic. A lot of libraries allows to convert Java POJO into JSON. The `Node` class is a classical POJO. Look at Jackson or GSON libraries. Also if you need a "hierarchy" property on top, you should wrap returned list into additional object (class with property `hierarchy`, or map with single entry with key "hierarchy")

Comment: Hi, when I added the main function inside Node class it gave me a lot of errors. Any idea why? Could you update your answer please?

Comment: @TeeJay I would not recommend to put the main method inside a POJO class (bean classes / POJO classes are meant to hold the data only), but if your declare the main method properly it should not be an issue. What kind of errors you received? Can you share the code somewhere like a https://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6cG7Kw6P File is called Node.java and "mapping.csv" has the csv contents

Comment: @TeeJay yes, you definitely mess up the code (e.g. including methods getters and setters inside the main method and other issues), the working example packed into a single class can be found here: https://pastebin.com/YzDpbAzL Note: is uses GSON library to serialize the object so you need to include it into your project path, can be found here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.1/

Comment: @TeeJay Also note that for leaves in the structure it generates empty JSON array, this can be quickly fixed by introducing a better way to populate children, for instance like this: https://pastebin.com/3afNGSCa

Comment: https://pastebin.com/utJiRC1J I am somehow getting null in "line" . I am sending the InputStreamReader instead of the filename since I am getting the file uploaded by the user every time.

Comment: @TeeJay This is a different issue you have in your code. You are trying to use `InputStream` you have taken from `MultipartFile` twice: 1) when you copy it to `StringWriter` using `IOUtils` and 2) when you pass the same input stream (which is already read to the end) to the convert logic of `fromCsvFile(...)` method. simply reopen the stream: `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(multipartFile.getInputStream());` !!! Important !!! `InputStream` can be used only one time to extract data.

Comment: How can I convert csv input of the form "Fruit,Apple,Red /n Fruit,Banana /n Fruit, Mango,Yellow,Pen /n Car,Audi" to my format of "parent,child"? Basically what can be done if the csv has the full hierarchy structure(from parent to leaf) on each line (redundant data)? Can I get it in my form of parent,child so that I can get the json eventually?

Comment: @TeeJay after `entry = line.split(",");` make a for-loop to go through all pairs, move the below logic into a separate method and call this method within the loop for every pair

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067291/how-to-convert-csv-which-has-leaf-value-and-entire-hierarchy-on-a-row-to-json-in  I have created a separate question for this! Please could you tell me how to achieve this? @Vladimir L.

Comment: I had an additional question (still do) which is why I have created a separate question thread. I have accepted your answer as correct. Could you please take a look at that question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Map is fine. Just use recursive function to write deeper levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String csv = ""
    + "Fruit, Mango\n"
    + "Fruit, Apple\n"
    + "Car, Audi\n"
    + "Apple, Red\n"
    + "Color, Brown\n"
    + "Red, Fire\n";
Set<String> topLevels = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<String> notTopLevels = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> labels = new LinkedHashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(csv))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        Map<String, Object> value = labels.computeIfAbsent(
            fields[1], k -> new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>());
        labels.computeIfAbsent(
            fields[0], k -> new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>())
            .put(fields[1], value);
        topLevels.add(fields[0]);
        notTopLevels.add(fields[1]);
    }
}
Map<String, Object> hierarchy = new LinkedHashMap<>();
topLevels.removeAll(notTopLevels);
for (String s : topLevels)
    hierarchy.put(s, labels.get(s));
System.out.println(hierarchy);
```

result:

```
{Fruit={Mango={}, Apple={Red={Fire={}}}}, Car={Audi={}}, Color={Brown={}}}
```