# How to convert CSV which has leaf value and entire hierarchy on a row to JSON in java?

Tags: java, json, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
Red,Apple,Fruit         //(red is the leaf and fruit is the main parent)
Orange,Apple,Fruit
Pen,Yellow,Mango,Fruit
Audi,Car
New,Car
Sky,Blue,Umbrella
```

I want to convert it to a JSON eventually something like this:

```
  "hierarchy" : [{
   "label": "Fruit",
   "children" : [ {label: "Mango"}, {label: "Apple", "children": [ {label:"Red"}]}
   ]
},
{
   "label" : "Car",
   "children" : [ {label: "Audi"}
   ]
},
{
   "label" : "Color",
   "children" : [ {label: "Brown"}
   ]
}]
```

The original CSV file will have rows representing the hierarchy (Leftmost will be the leaf value i.e. lowest granularity and then Level1,Level2,Level 3etc where Level 1 represents the main parent). Right now, the code works when the CSV is of the following (parent,child) format:

```
Fruit, Mango
Fruit, Apple
Car, Audi
Apple, Red
Color, Brown
```

Function in Java:

```
 try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String parentName, childName;
            String[] entry;

            String line = input.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                entry = line.split(",");
                parentName = entry[0].trim();
                childName = entry[1].trim();

                // find or create
                Node node = existingNodes.get(parentName);
                if (node == null) {
                    // new top level node
                    node = new Node();
                    node.setLabel(parentName);
                    root.addChild(node);
                    existingNodes.put(parentName, node);
                }

                // add child
                Node child = new Node();
                child.setLabel(childName);
                node.addChild(child);
                existingNodes.put(childName, child);

                // next line
                line = input.readLine();
            }
        }

        return root.getChildren();
    }
```

What needs to be done to deal with the above mentioned CSV file instead? (leaf value at the left and remaining hierarchy on the right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021567/converting-from-csv-to-json-by-using-map-for-more-than-1-depth-level), and similar to what @janos already provided, this is how I suggested to implement it:

```
public static List<Node> fromCsvFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    Node root = new Node();
    Map<String, Node> existingNodes = new HashMap<>();

    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] elements = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            for (int i = elements.length; i > 1; i--) {
                addPair(elements[i - 1], elements[i - 2], root, existingNodes);
            }
        }
    }

    return root.getChildren();
}

private static void addPair(String parentName, String childName, Node root, Map<String, Node> existingNodes) {
    if (!existingNodes.containsKey(childName)) {
        // find or create
        Node node = existingNodes.get(parentName);
        if (node == null) {
            // new top level node
            node = new Node();
            node.setLabel(parentName);
            root.addChild(node);
            existingNodes.put(parentName, node);
        }

        // add child
        Node child = new Node();
        child.setLabel(childName);
        node.addChild(child);
        existingNodes.put(childName, child);
    }
}
```

See full example here: https://pastebin.com/fVj4atwa

You have an issue in your example though: Fruit is a child of Apple and child of Pen, this is not possible in a tree structure.

Comment: I have updated the question. The format of CSV is Leaf value, Level 1, Level 2, level 3 (i.e Level 1 is the main parent -> Level 2 -> Level 3) Level 3 is leaf value's immediate parent

Comment: Consider previous file format : From your earlier code I get 3 children for Fruit. Apple appears twice (instead should appear just once). Correct hierarchy structure would be : Fruit->Apple, Mango .  Apple->Red,Orange . Mango->Yellow->pen . Car->Audi,New . Blue->Umbrella->Sky . What is happening now is Apple appears as two different children of Fruit. This happens for depth > 1

Comment: @TeeJay because you have a **conflicting** input in your CSV example (the one with multi-levels): 1st row - Apple is a child of Red, 2nd row - Apple is a child of Orange

Comment: No, the CSV is structured from left-to-right. Apple is a child of Fruit. Red,Orange and children of Apple. The csv has to be read from left to right. Leftmost value is the leaf and rightmost represents the main parent (Highest level)

Comment: @TeeJay how about your first comment here above: "The format of CSV is Leaf value, Level 1, Level 2, level 3 (i.e Level 1 is the main parent -> Level 2 -> Level 3)" :) did you change you mind again? and Level 3 is the main parent?

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion! I tried your previous code and hence had written "consider previous file format". How could this be solved for Leaf value, Level n, level n-1,...Level 1 (Level 1 is main parent). Sorry for the edit

Comment: @TeeJay this should work for valid data in CSV file => https://pastebin.com/fVj4atwa

Comment: Example of invalid data: 1st row "Red,Apple,Fruit", 2nd row "Orange,Apple,Car" - Apple appears to be a child of Fruit and Car. This is not possible to represent in tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

> What needs to be done to deal with the above mentioned CSV file instead? (leaf value at the left and remaining hierarchy on the right?)

Instead of taking the first column as the parent and second as the child,
take the last as the parent,
and then iteratively add the children.

```
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String line = input.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String parentName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // find or create
        Node node = existingNodes.get(parentName);
        if (node == null) {
            // new top level node
            node = new Node();
            node.setLabel(parentName);
            root.addChild(node);
            existingNodes.put(parentName, node);
        }

        Node parent = node;
        for (int i = parts.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            String childName = parts[i];
            Node child = existingNodes.get(childName);
            if (child == null) {
                child = new Node();
                child.setLabel(childName);
                parent.addChild(child);
                existingNodes.put(childName, child);
            }
            parent = child;
        }

        line = input.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the file format in the question. It is Leaf value, Level 1, Level 2, level 3 (i.e Level 1 is the main parent -> Level 2 -> Level 3) Level 3 is leaf value's immediate parent

Comment: @TeeJay I don't understand your change. Can you explain with two concrete examples, let's say with `Orange,Fruit,Apple` and with `Pen,Fruit,Mango,Yellow`, what is your target hierarchy.

Comment: Consider the initial problem statement and forget the change. I tried the above code. The hierarchy shows up fine but has the following issue : "Fruit" has 3 children in the hierarchy ("apple", "apple","mango"). It should have had just apple and mango and "red","orange" should be children of apple instead of creating separate children. It does not work correctly for depth more than 1, Im guessing?

Comment: @TeeJay I see your point. Updated the code accordingly, but it's a bit hard to debug blindly, so it might still not be perfect. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It kind of messes up. Fruit has two children now - Apple and Mango. But Apple has just Red (skips orange). Also, Car-> Audi, New is missing. (I think it skipped if level was just 1?)

Comment: @TeeJay I don't see my mistake. I think it should work. But that also depends on your other parts of the code working well, such as the `addChild` method, and all the other code that you use but is not included in your question. But do you get the idea of iteratively adding child nodes? That's the most important point. You should be able to debug the details in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting `line`, you iterate the `entry` array from right to left, looking up the name, adding it if not found.

E.g. after processing the first line `Red,Apple,Fruit`, you'd have a root node with label `Fruit`, who has a child labeled `Apple`, and it has a child labeled `Red`.

When you then process line `Orange,Apple,Fruit`, you start at the root of your hierarchy, looking for node labeled `Fruit`. With that node in hand, you look for child labeled `Apple`. With that node in hand, you look for child labeled `Orange`, and since you don't find it, you add `Orange` as another child of `Apple`.